# MOQ Async IDs Setting

Tags: mocking, moq

I am trying to set the ID of the Dto I am sending   `It.IsAny<int>()`.

How do I set this?

```
     _service.Setup(x => x.GetDtoAsync(It.IsAny<int>())).ReturnsAsync(new Dto()
        {
           Id = ????? 
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Returns<T>(Func<T, TResult>)`](http://www.nudoq.org/#!/Packages/Moq/Moq/IReturns(TMock,TResult)/M/Returns(T)) and return a completed `Task`.

```
_service.Setup(x => x.GetDtoAsync(It.IsAny<int>()))
    .Returns<int>(id => Task.FromResult(new Dto { Id = id }));
```